# Postgres SQL left outer join on the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such query:

```
SELECT c.name, i.name FROM inv_invoice_items c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_invoice_items i ON i.name = c.name
WHERE c.id_invoice = 2108 AND i.id_invoice = (SELECT id_invoice FROM inv_invoices WHERE id =   2108)
```

For this query I have such result:

```
name  | name
-------------
pen   | pen
```

but for select without join:

```
SELECT c.name FROM inv_invoice_items c
WHERE c.id_invoice = 2108
```

the result is:

```
name
------
pen
pencil
```

and second query:

```
SELECT i.name FROM inv_invoice_items i
WHERE i.id_invoice = (SELECT id_invoice FROM inv_invoices WHERE id = 2108)
```

gives result:

```
name
------
pen
```

I would expect for my first join query result:

```
name   | name
---------------
pen    | pen
pencil | NULL
```

How to achieve such result? I thought that way should work LEFT OUTER JOIN. Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Ps. I need to catch differences in invoice items of corrective and corrected (related ) invoice.

Some sample data:

```
create table inv_invoices (id bigint, id_invoice bigint, primary key(id));
create table inv_invoice_items (id bigint, id_invoice bigint NOT NULL, name character varying(100) NOT NULL, primary key (id));
insert into inv_invoices values (2105, NULL), (2106, NULL), (2107, NULL), (2108, 2106);
insert into inv_invoice_items values (1000, 2105, 'pen'), (1001, 2105, 'pencil'), (1002,2106, 'pen'), (1003, 2107, 'rubber'), 
(1004, 2107, 'pencil'), (1005, 2108, 'pen'), (1006, 2108, 'pencil');
```

Comment: Remove the second Expression in AND:    i.id_invoice = (SELECT id_invoice FROM inv_invoices WHERE id =   2108)  . It's been useless here I guess

Comment: Not exactly. Removing second AND cause other result - also not expected - rows: pen, pen; pen, pen; pen, pen; pencil, pencil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Try this instead:</strike>

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name, i.name 
FROM inv_invoice_items            AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_invoice_items AS i   ON i.name       = c.name 
                                        AND c.id_invoice = 2108
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_invoices      AS i2  ON i.id_invoice = i2.id_invoice 
                                        AND i2.id        = 2108;
```

---

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t.name AS name1,
  v.name AS name2
FROM
(
  SELECT c.name 
  FROM inv_invoice_items c
  WHERE c.id_invoice = 2108
) AS t
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT i.name 
  FROM inv_invoice_items i
  WHERE i.id_invoice = (SELECT id_invoice 
                        FROM inv_invoices 
                        WHERE id = 2108)
) AS v ON t.name = v.name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/29e5b/12)

This will give you:

```
|  NAME1 |  NAME2 |
-------------------
|    pen |    pen |
| pencil | (null) |
```

Comment: Hello Mahmoud. Now I have in the left column all items of inv_invoice_items and in the right one - several times "pen" and "pencil" when the same value is in the left column. Any suggestions?

Comment: @robson - Try adding the keyword `DISTINCT` : `SELECT DISTINCT c.name, i.name ...` instead. Also try to post some sample data from the two tables please.

Comment: DISTINCT didn't help. Please see my first post - I've added some sample data to ilustrate the problem compatibile with our queries. Thank you.